# Get text from sentence

Tags: c#, asp.net, trim

in asp.net C#

let's say i want to store only the word "Batu Pahat" to database from following sentence

```
Conditions for Batu Pahat, MY at 11:00 am MYT
```

or "Mersing" from the following sentence?

```
Conditions for Mersing, MY at 12:00 pm MYT
```

Any one knows any algoritham to get this text? please help :)

**UPDATE**

Example sentences

> Conditions for Kangar, MY at 10:00 am MYT 
>   Conditions for Batu Pahat, MY at 11:00 am MYT
>   Conditions for Mersing, MY at 11:30 am MYT    
>   Conditions for Segamat, MY at 12:00 pm MYT
>   Conditions for Johor Bahru Perdana, MY at 11:00 am MYT
>   Conditions for Muar, MY at 03:00 am MYT

**Extra Info**

The time "11:00 am" is not fixed.

Comment: Is your sentence structure fixed? IF yes, would you not be able to pull a substring based on indexes or text matches?

Comment: if it is fixed, then can use substring..

Comment: Updated the question. i believe only the text i want to extract is not fixed. the rest should be fixed. any idea? :)
@ryadavilli, i think what u said is the solution. please don't mind showing me how u do it :) i am beginner in c#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or without using Regex (as an alternative to the other answer), and only if the structure is fixed.

```
string startIgnorePart = "Conditions for ";
string findBefore = ",";
string original = "Conditions for Mersing, MY at 11:00 am MYT";
string extracted = original.Substring(startIgnorePart.Length, original.IndexOf(findBefore) - startIgnorePart.Length);
Console.WriteLine(extracted);
```

Comment: so i guess u ignore the starting part. and then stop once "," is found? i try it out now. yes the structure is fixed

Comment: I ignore it in the sense that when i look for the target value, i start only after the "Conditions for" part and end at wherever i find a ",". So the value in between is what I would need. You can change the string or do a +/- in the indexes if you require the space after "for" or the , itself.

Answer (score 3):

Regex should be able to help you out.  I haven't tested this, but something like this should work.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("Conditions for (.*),");
var v = regex.Match("Conditions for Kangar, MY at 11:00 am MYT");
```